# How to have a div at last if the flex items go to new row vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have an array of tags. i want to show single row of tags and if it doesn't fit in one row (depending upon the screen size ) than i want to hide the tag that doesn't fit and show a button that display all tags

```
<div class="tags-wrapper">
  <div class="tags">
    <div v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag.id" class="tags__item">{{ tag.title }}</div>
    <div class="tags__item--loadMore" v-if="loadMore"><span>...</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The tag size in it is variable and i dont want to specify it.

This is the css

```
.tags-wrapper {
    .tags {
        display: flex;
        max-height: 16px;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        &__item {
            height: 16px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the max-height on a button click

Comment: i think you didn't understand the issue i want to show the button when it doesn't fit in row if it fits i don't want to show it.

Comment: You could remove `max-height` then check the `height` with js and if its larger than `16px` add `max-height: 16px;` and the button to toggle it